# Audio play() not working on Android 4.4 mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-streaming, android-4.4-kitkat, audio-player

I am trying to play a simple audio file via javascript on page load which works on browsers and mobile devices but same not working with android 4.4 version.

Below is the code snippet:

```
<audio controls id="player">
  <source src="testaudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<script>
   var audiofile = document.getElementById("player")[0];
   audiofile.load();
   audiofile.play();
</script>
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser?  And, do you have a packet capture showing if the file is ever requested?  Anything in the console?

Comment: Hi Brad, I am checking with Samsung Galaxy s5 native browser, also tried with google chrome and its same result. No errors found in console.

Comment: A packet capture would be helpful.